# When resizing Windows Explorer on Windows 8 it crashes?

Tags: windows-explorer, crash, windows-8

I have following problem: When I try to change size of any explorer window from maximized to some size getting following screen

[image]

It blinks 20-30 times, then crashes. Also it changes it's size every time into this square size.  Here is event viewer result:

```
The program Explorer.EXE version 6.2.9200.16384 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
 Process ID: 10f8
 Start Time: 01cd9e3e189fe3d1
 Termination Time: 0
 Application Path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
 Report Id: ea71d13a-0a32-11e2-be92-3859f90026b6
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

What can be issue? Is there any way to fix explorer crashes? Or only way is reinstalling windows?

Comment: Could be a video driver issue. If so, I guess you'll just need to wait for updated drivers for Win8.

Comment: Is the problem exclusive to the Explorer ? Does other apps work properly ?

Comment: @allquixotic - There isn't anything true about your comment. I really wish we could vote comments n a situation like your comment.  The fact the display flashes indicates without a single doubt this is a driver problem.  The artifact that happens also proves this is the cause.  This has nothing to do with lack of service packs, it is the fact, the driver is unstable which wasn't written by Microsoft my guess you have a beta version.

Comment: @Ramhound: There isn't anything true about your comment. I really wish we could vote comments in a situation like your comment. The fact is that Windows Explorer is blinking indicates without a single doubt that this is not necessarily a driver problem. The artifact that happens also doesn't proof this is the cause. This might have something to do with the lack of service packs, it is the fact, the drivers might be completely stable and don't have to be written by Microsoft so version doesn't matter.

Comment: @Tural: Can you look in the Action Center control panel whether there is a report available and could you share the files with us so we can inspect what's exactly happening and hopefully see the root cause? If that doesn't result in anything useful we can attempt to capture a trace of it instead...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that is related your video drivers/adapter.  Start by upgrading the drivers for that to Windows 8 compatible drivers.  Check to see if it happens in safe mode, that will more than likely tell you if it is a driver, as safe mode loads a generic driver.

Try both the WDM driver and the official driver from the manufacturer of the video card.

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced this issue on Windows 10. 
There is a very simple solution after all :)

> Check if you have enabled extra panes like the preview or navigation pane in explorer. Simply reset your views to the usual Large Icons, Small Icons, Details etc and DO NOT select any navigation/PREVIEW pane.

Once I disabled the preview pane, the explorer window could resize to the smallest size and stop flickering!

Comment: Where did your quote come from? Could you edit your answer to include the source?

Comment: Thanks, very simple. All working for me now :)

Answer (score 1):

On this page: [Gathering of Tweakers, a dutch IT forum](http://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_messages/1512966/6) someone has had the exact same error message, obviously without the details of the "problem history in the Action Center control panel" I can't really say more than that. If you provided that information we would probably have more to go on, or it might at least give some clue.

See below (translated):

> After a fresh install I have another problem during the boot. The taskbar appears to be freezing and after clicking on it and then on the desktop it comes back after a few seconds.
>
> In the `eventvwr` I came to this:
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------
> The program Explorer.EXE version 6.2.9200.16384 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
> Process ID: 8B8
> StartTime: 01cd815d6a10d264
> Termination Time: 0
> Application Path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
> Report Id: b2595ccb-ED50-11e1-be7b-002522be6759
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:
> ---------------------------------------
> ```
>
> I can not find the cause of this... I strongly suspect it's a driver. But last day it was fine and there is nothing else installed. The last thing I did was the "Windows Experience Index" test.

You see he notes the last thing done was the windows experience index test, maybe you did that last too?
Other users of that forum have indicated it could be a driver issue, so try updating them as in the other answer.

Something else worth waiting for is the hotfixes to be release when windows 8 is officially released, these kind of issues may be fixed then.

Comment: `taskbar appears to be freezing` is not the same problem as `resizing Windows Explorer freezes`?

Comment: Ok, maybe "Exact same problem" is the wrong wording but the error message and possibly the cause is the same.

Comment: How can you be so sure of that without having access to either report? The files from the report actually make "maybe" and "possibly" two impossible words to use, as you can see "what" actually happened.

Comment: I'm going on what is given. Since this was posted a month ago I thought we probably wouldn't get any more information so posted an answer that I thought might help someone in the future. If it's not appropriate please delete it. :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, upvoted your answer but was just wondering if you saw something more.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Preview Pane works, after which you are able to re-enable the Preview Pane and it still works.  No need to check drivers, it's a crash state of Preview Pane trying to re-load the preview from before the crash and causing a loop.